# What is the most efficient way to retrieve associated subitems for items in the same MongoDB collection?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection that stores both item and subitem documents. Each item document can have multiple subitems, and they are linked by a "parent_id" field within the same collection. I need to efficiently retrieve an item along with its associated subitems. The number of subitems per item can vary, but it is limited to a maximum of 50 initially, with the possibility of increasing in the future.

Considering that the item and subitem documents are in the same collection, I am exploring two options for efficient retrieval and would like guidance on the best approach:

Using the `$lookup` aggregation pipeline stage to perform a joint operation between the item and subitem documents within the same collection. This would involve creating a pipeline that matches the item document, performs a lookup to fetch the associated subitems, and returns the result as a single query.

Fetching the item document first and then querying for the associated subitems by matching the "parent_id" field. I would iterate over the list of item documents and append the corresponding subitems.

Considering the potential variability in the number of subitems per item and the requirement for optimal performance, which approach would be more efficient? Are there any performance considerations or best practices I should be aware of when dealing with this scenario?

If the `$lookup` approach is recommended, I would appreciate guidance on how to structure the pipeline for efficiently retrieving the associated subitems for each item.

This is my sample `$lookup` query,

```
{
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Queens",
      "localField": "_item_id",
      "foreignField": "_parent_id",
      "as": "Subitems"
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without knowing more about your collection/documents and what you want to retrieve from the query, it's difficult to provide any precise guidance.  There would presumably be less network traffic with a single query using `"$lookup"` or `"$graphLookup"`.  You could implement both of your proposed approaches and determine which has better performance for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you please explain, what more details you want? I'll post my sample data model, Please check. The item count can be up to 1,00,000 and the subitem inside an item will be 50. In the future, it can scale up to 100.

[
  {
    "_id": "QUEE-0004",
    "_item_id": "QUEE-0004",
    "Name": "Item Name"
  },
  {
    "_id": "Pk75xgEJ33M4",
    "_item_id": "QUEE-0004-01",
    "_parent_id": "QUEE-0004"
  }
]

@rickhg12hs

Comment: _"Each item document can have multiple subitems..."_  Are these _"subitems"_ present in the collection documents? ... or does this come from the app/client?  Perhaps if you showed some code/pseudocode of each option you are considering, it would be easier to assess.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with "self-lookup" is reasonable.  Let's assume the collection looks like this:

```js
    // These are "main" items:
    {_item_id: "A1", color: "red"}
    ,{_item_id: "A2", color: "red"}
    ,{_item_id: "A3", color: "green"}
    ,{_item_id: "A4", color: "green"}

    // These are "subitems":
    ,{_parent_id: "A1", other: "foo"}
    ,{_parent_id: "A1", other: "bar"}
    ,{_parent_id: "A1", other: "baz"}

    ,{_parent_id: "A2", other: "corn"}
    ,{_parent_id: "A2", other: "dog"}
```

Here is a pipeline that will fetch the main items you seek and capture in an array field all the subitems associated with the main item:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    //  First, $match on anything you want. If the field name exists in 
    //  both main and subitem docs, then you would have to explicitly 
    //  exclude it, e.g.:
    //          {$match: {color: "red", _parent_id:null}}
    //  but keep it simple for now:
   {$match: {color: "red"}}

    //  Do the self-lookup:
    ,{$lookup: {from: "foo", localField: "_item_id", foreignField: "_parent_id", as: "Z"}}
])
```

This yields:

```js
 _id: 0,
  _item_id: 'A1',
  color: 'red',
  Z: [
    {
      _id: 4,
      _parent_id: 'A1',
      other: 'foo'
    },
    {
      _id: 5,
      _parent_id: 'A1',
      other: 'bar'
    },
    {
      _id: 6,
      _parent_id: 'A1',
      other: 'baz'
    }
  ]
}
{
  _id: 1,
  _item_id: 'A2',
  color: 'red',
  Z: [
    {
      _id: 7,
      _parent_id: 'A2',
      other: 'corn'
    },
    {
      _id: 8,
      _parent_id: 'A2',
      other: 'dog'
    }
  ]
}
```

Also:  I recommend not using field names with leading underscores.  It's a convention thing, nothing more.